# Where to ask an open question about which progamming language is better?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked a question on Stack Overflow that got 4 negative points. I was told this happened because Stack Overflow is made for closed and accurate answers. My question was: Which programming language should I learn to make a conditional answer survey? Obviously I added everything I would include in my algorithm and additional info. So, is there a Stack Exchange website where I can get some decent opinions?

Comment: Yahoo Answers? Quora?

Comment: If you're interested in getting flamed, you can try out one of the chatrooms.

Comment: @Mysticial I guess the best practice for that would be to go to Lounge and start with saying that C++ sucks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no site in the network that fits such a question.

Your question has two problems:

1. It is too broad. If you want to write one answer that covers all possible programming languages that can be used and would be a good fit, you would need an entire book-style answer to list them all.
2. If you say, *no I don't want a book-style answer, just tell me the language you think is best*, you question is more about the opinion of every single user than a conclusive answer. I am pretty sure you end up with as many opinions as there are language tags on Stack Overflow. (Hence the term "primarily opinion based" which is used as a close reason.) That is not helpful.

That is the reason we don't want such questions on any site in the network.